# After installing TypeScript, why does "Peek Definition" in Visual Studio Code stop working?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm very new to TypeScript and am trying to figure why, when transitioning a project to TypeScript in Visual Studio Code, "Peek Definition" stops working.

Before transitioning to TypeScript, I'm using `jsconfig.json` to set up Webpack aliases. After adding TypeScript, I'm using `tsconfig.json` to do the same thing, with additional configuration options I don't fully understand yet.

Without TypeScript, when hovering over a component, I'll see something like,

```js
(alias) module ComponentWrapper
(alias) const ComponentWrapper: {
    ({ children }: {
        children: any;
    }): JSX.Element;
    displayName: string;
    propTypes: {
        something: PropTypes.Requireable<string>;
    };
    defaultProps: {};
}
import ComponentWrapper
```

And CMD + click will take me to that file.  However, in the TypeScript project, doing the same thing, when hovering I see

```js
import ComponentWrapper
```

And CMD + click just takes me to the top of the file to the `import` statement.

My `jsconfig.json` looks like

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@modules/*": ["src/modules/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["src/utils/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

While my `tsconfig.json` looks like

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@modules/*": ["src/modules/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["src/utils/*"]
    },
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "es2017"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false,
    "target": "ES2019",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "exclude": [".github", ".next", "node_modules", "public"],
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: It should work fine after you reload vs code

Comment: @AluanHaddad, thanks, but that doesn't fix it. It's something I've been trying to figure out for weeks now and I've reloaded VSC after each attempted fix.

Comment: I've done this hundreds of times and it works fine